# GoogleBetterAds - violatingSites.list - google-apis-explorer

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I can get a list of summaries of violating sites, using the following link: 
[https://developers.google.com/ad-experience-report/[...]/violatingSites/list](https://developers.google.com/ad-experience-report/v1/reference/rest/v1/violatingSites/list)

My questions:

- Is this list exhaustive?
- If not, is it possible to get an exhaustive list (or not) and how?
- Is it possible to know how these websites are pulled (the share of websites analysed, etc)?

Comment: What's size (strlen or {M|k}o) of your actual API return?

Answer (score 0):

> ## - Is this list exhaustive?

**What's size of your actual API return?**

- If you have an API return statement increasingly longer and longer with new data at each new request, you can think have the exhaustive list (with a possible update
  latency).
- If the API return statement have always same size with different data, in example old data will not appears and it replaced by new data, it's not exhaustive.

> ## - If not, is it possible to get an exhaustive list (or not) and how?

*I have no idea at the moment, the total number of websites can be in billion ...*

> ## - Is it possible to know how these websites are pulled (the share of websites analysed, etc)?

*I have no idea for the moment too, I think it is either a confidential process or that it is described in the general conditions and subtily in the documentation...*

Comment: I compared the new last with a previous one and they are both of length 1590.

Comment: Ok, they contains exactly same or differents data?

Comment: I checked again, yes they are perfectly the same